# c++ Is it possible and good practice to overwrite inheritance?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Is the following structure in c++ doable and recommended?

```
class IColour{}

class Grey: public IColour {}

class DarkGrey: public IColour {}

class IMaterial {}

class Rock: public Material, public Grey {}

class Basalt : public Rock, public DarkGrey {}
```

Is there a way to overwrite the inheritance of a base class in a derived class? That is, is it possible to overwrite the inheritance of Grey with DarkGrey in Basalt?

Comment: you'd be better off to make these properties of your class, i.e. Colour being it's own type and then you can add a Grey Colour or Dark Grey Colour as a member, personally I'd prefer composition over inheritance here

Comment: It's called virtual inheritance. It has its costs. And it's usually indicative of a design that should be redone.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't think virtual inheritance (i.e., several "diamond-shaped" inheritance paths to the same base class which still lead only to one base class object) is the issue here. Yes, with virtual inheritance `Basalt` would only have one `IColour` subobject; but it would still have both a `Grey` *and* a `DarkGrey` subobject.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - This cluster (redacted) of a design will require almost all the classes to inherit virtually. That's what I meant by it being indicative of a poor design.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm just saying that virtual inheritance does not address the question.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - I disagree. The OP asked how the multiple instances of base classes can be removed, and is it good practice to do so. The first answer is "yes" via virtual inheritance everywhere, and the second is "no" because you have virtual inheritance everywhere.

Comment: @StoryTeller As an aside, I find your strong opposition against virtual inheritance interesting. I think I have probably never used it, but in other languages which have "proper" interfaces as a language feature (e.g. C#, Java) it is not uncommon to "tag" classes via inheritance, for example to indicate a capability (is an `IColorable` == "can be colored" and provides member functions for it). I know that general problems with multiple inheritance are better known these days, and it is mostly avoided. Is that true for "tagging interfaces" as well?

Comment: @StoryTeller Re "remove multiple instances of a base class": No, he wants to *replace* one class (`Grey`) with another, different one (`DarkGrey`), much like a value. He does not ask how to collapse two subobjects of *identical type* which are reached through two different inheritance paths into one.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - I'm not sure how other languages handle multiple inheritance from the same tag, but I assume it's easier to resolve the ambiguity when no state is involved. I don't oppose is as a rule (the standard stream library makes beautiful use of it). But unless carefully used, they tend to creep up in poor designs, I find.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - *"Is there a way to overwrite the inheritance of a base class in a derived class"* strongly sounds to to me like asking how to avoid the duplicate sub-objects. So let's agree to disagree on this.

Comment: @StoryTeller Well, did you read all the way to the last sentence, included, and the source?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider -- I did, but I assumed, like any sane person would, that "DarkGray" is-a "Gray". And if it isn't, the whole premise is silly. If this isn't a copy-paste error, it's really poorly thought out. Anyway Richard Hodges' answer addresses that particular problem as well.

Comment: @StoryTeller You know, maybe you are right and the OP just forgot to code that inheritance (or else he should have used some other darn color).

Answer (score 6):

Inheritance describes an "is a kind of" relationship.

Basalt is not a "kind of" dark grey. Arguably it's better to describe the colour as a property, since every rock *has* a colour, it's not a *kind of* colour.

Something like this:

```
class IColour{};

class Grey: public IColour {};

class DarkGrey: public IColour {};

const IColour& dark_grey()
{
  static DarkGrey _ {};
  return _;
}

const IColour& grey()
{
  static Grey _ {};
  return _;
}

class IMaterial {
  virtual const IColour& get_colour() const = 0;
};

class Rock: public IMaterial
{
    const IColour& get_colour() const override {
        return grey();
    }
};

class Basalt : public Rock
{
    const IColour& get_colour() const override {
        return dark_grey();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redefine a type, you can only create new ones.
So in essence when you write

```
class Basalt : public Rock, public DarkGrey {}
```

Yo more or less imply

```
class Basalt : public Material, public Grey {}, public DarkGrey {}
```

Here the `DarkGrey` doesn't replace the `Grey`, it is added next to it